# Web Forms, Simple Membership & Database First to Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, ef-database-first

My title is a bit complex, but I will break down really simply what I am doing here.

I have an existing database with about 20 tables. I have a project that my partner has decided that we should use the old Simple Membership over Identity. This is no longer an option on the table, we have finalized that decision. WE will be creating the project in Web Forms using Visual Studio 2012 because that is what we have licenses for.

**Step 1)** I started a new project in VS 2012 using Web Forms and I pointed the Default Connection String at my current database and registered a few users. This created the tables I needed for membership in my SQL Server 2012 database.

**Step 2)** I did some relational mapping in my database connecting existing tables to the new membership UserID's where needed so that my existing tables are now related to the membership stuff.

**Step 3)** Here is where I am a bit lost because normally I have used SqlDataSources with Web Forms in the past. I have some experience with MVC so I would like to do things differently in this web forms project and start from Database First and import my database tables into a Data Access Layer, I'm thinking of using a Class Library for this.

MY QUESTION: **When importing my EDMX for database first. Should I

A) Bring in all of the tables (Existing Tables + New Membership Tables)

B) Just bring in the Tables that are NOT part of Membership?

C) Bring in my Existing Tables and only the User and Membership table? or
D) Do you have any other idea?**

My reasoning for this question is that I know that I can access the Membership stuff in the Web Forms Project but will it possibly be needed in the Class Library since my application will eventually be very User centric. Lots of tracking of user time and logins, assigning tasks and projects, permissions to that user etc.. I was leaning toward **(A)**

I know this is a very complex question or maybe I should say it may have many answers all due to things that I may not know yet or I have not explained fully. But I'm looking for some direction as I have never used a Class Library or Database first in this way or in a Web Forms Application.

**Snapshot of Database:**

[image: e]

Comment: The `ArchiUsers` table is the old user table from an old application and will most likely not be used, it's there because it has some existing user data in it. Pretty much everything else I plan on using and I have mapped out their relationships including connecting them to the membership user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to include the Membership tables in the EF model. As you pointed out, the Membership class will handle it as long as you have it properly configured in the Web.Config file.

You should import only those tables that are related to your application.

You would only import the membership tables only if you are building a custom membership provider, which is old news by now.

At least, I personally don't do it. This also helps to keep the EF model with just what I need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I were doing a lot of work with the UserID and Roles within my application, would it then be smart to maybe pull just those into my entities? This way I could for instance create a gridview that that lets the user select from users and assign them to a specific task. Or would the access that I have already in my project allow that. Seems it may be easier to pull the User and Roles tables in for that reason. BTW,I appreciate your help!

Comment: Second question) If I pull in a database with EF using database first and arrange my model, etc.. I then can connect to it with a EntityDataSource, but If before I pull in those entities, I create a Class library and then use database first to pull those tables into an entity model within the class library, would I then be using an ObjectDataSource to bind to it? Just let me know if I'm completely off base there.